# I cant find active input border property on developer tools

Tags: css

When click any input fields on the contact form, while it is active, its border convert to blue.The border color depends form-control class.I know it, because when I remove the form-control class, also the blue color removes.However, I cant find the css code of the active color on google chrome developer tools.I searched "border" in styles but I couldnt find related things even also search for form-control class.

Why? I need same css

http://unlockdesizn.com/html/health-and-beauty/be-medical/demo/ulockd-booking-form.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The border comes from boostrap.min.css

```
.form-control:focus {
    border-color: #66afe9;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The selector you are looking for is `.form-control:focus` which is adding a border color and `box-shadow` (currently coming from bootstraps styles).